# Sublime Text 2 autocomplete API

Tags: plugins, autocomplete, sublimetext2

I write plugin for Sublime Text 2 and I want use autocomplete feauture. But I can't understand how it works. In official API docs there is the method of class .View called `showCompletions(point, prefix, [completions])` but I have error: **AttributeError: 'View' object has no attribute 'showCompletions'**. Is there any example how use autocomplete method in plugin creation correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the name of the function you posted, you are probably looking at ST1 docs. Here are the ST2 docs. http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html

That being said, the documentation is incomplete, and does not describe the completion behavior. Below is a snippet of code to create a plugin that will populate an entry in the auto complete list. The return value contains a list of tuples specifying the display text and the insert text. Please comment if you need additional clarification, but this should get you started in the right direction.

```
class EventListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_query_completions(self, view, prefix, locations):
        return [("Text to display in completion list", "Text to insert")]
```